# Why are edits on tag wikis strictly rate limited?

Tags: support, suggested-edits, tag-wiki

I was suggesting a tag wiki excerpt a moment ago and noticed on submission that I'd made a typo.  When I attempted to immediately edit this out to change my suggestion, I was presented with a rate limiter of:

> You can perform this action again in 30 seconds

As far as I'm aware this isn't the case for normal edits, typos in their suggestion can be *immediately* corrected.  What's the reason behind the difference?

Comment: There are fewer people who can (1) review wiki suggestions and fewer still that can (2) immediately fix them.

Comment: @UndotheSnowman seems reasonable!  Not sure that a 30 second wait time would reduce potential for abuse though, or indeed matter in cases like this where the double action results in a single suggestion in the queue.

Comment: Was this a suggested edit or an immediate edit? Had anyone started to review the edit when you submitted the correction?

Comment: @giles  Suggested Edit, with no reviews done at the time of resubmission :)

Comment: I agree, this 30-second limit is too harsh. That's annoying when editing tags.